# Refresh the listview on deleting the item from there

Tags: android, string, listview, android-listview

Hey guy i am working on app which contains listview in which installed apps are populated with some buttons such as uninstall.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
PackageManager packageManager;
List<ApplicationInfo> applist;
Listadapter listadapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
         AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new   AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose option")
            .setItems(R.array.options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
                            try {
                                Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                                if (intent != null) {
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ApplicationInfo app1 = applist.get(position);
                            Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + app1.packageName);
                            Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
                            startActivity(uninstallIntent);
                            applist.remove(listadapter.getItem(position));
                            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)
            .show();

}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return applist;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist =  checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

        listadapter = new Listadapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "loading apps info,,,");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        listadapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

When i click on uninstall ,the app position gets deleted first before even uninstalling the app.

This is strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AppSharer</string>
    <string-array name="options">
        <item>Open App</item>
        <item>uninstall</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

How should i refresh the listview once i delete the item.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from question is that you must be having problem in case user clicked yes to uninstall but from settings screen user comes back to app without uninstalling it. For that case create a variable Boolean which will be true if user clicked yes on uninstall and save app package name in string variable at instance level and in on resume method  of class check if user Boolean is true then check if defined package exist or not and if it does not exist update your list view. Please refer this, I have also added comments to notify you what changes are made

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    PackageManager packageManager;
    List<ApplicationInfo> applist;
    Listadapter listadapter;
    // add three variables
    String packageName="";
    boolean isUnInstallClicked;
    int mPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
             AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new   AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose option")
                .setItems(R.array.options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
                                try {
                                    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                                    if (intent != null) {
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                ApplicationInfo app1 = applist.get(position);
                                Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + app1.packageName);
                                Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
                                startActivity(uninstallIntent);
                                //remove applist.remove and notify from here and add it to on resume
                                packageName=app1.packageName;
                                isUnInstallClicked=true;
                                mPosition=position;

                                break;
                            case 2:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)
                .show();

    }
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            // here check for whether unistall was clicked and was app unistalled
            if(isUnInstallClicked && !appInstalledOrNot(packageName)){
                //check whther app unistalled or not

                applist.remove(listadapter.getItem(position));
                listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist =  checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

            listadapter = new Listadapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            setListAdapter(listadapter);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "loading apps info,,,");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
            listadapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

Comment: Bro actually uninstall is working fine...but even after the app is uninstalled i see that app in my listview ...for this i tried adapter.notifydatasetcange but this is nt working or i maybe placing it in some wrong place...

Comment: Can u please get me some code refreshing listview on resume.thanx

Comment: in applist.remove(listadapter.getItem(position)) applsit is listview object or arraylist object?

Comment: I have edited and posted my complete code please tell me where am i wrong.

Comment: I am not sure on this but instead of applist.remove(listadapter.getItem(position)) use applist.remove((position)  and remove listadapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated() from onPause

Comment: Ok i removed listadapter from onpause....and used applist.remove (position) but still the position gets removed as soon as i click on case 1: condition...i need to remove dat position if and only if app uninstallation is confirmed.

Comment: nice to see..it helped you

Comment: vishal can u help on this also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194616/copying-apk-file-to-specified-folder

Comment: you are already metion in your code.. cool... adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); this one is refresh the adapter list.