# Copying ".apk" file to specified folder

Tags: android, image, file, android-listview, inputstream

I am trying to copy apk of installed app from listview to some specified folder.Copying of apk is working fine...But each time i click on app to copy its apk ..."phone.apk" gets copied to destination folder with diff package name.
Here is code of file copying.

```
              public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
PackageManager packageManager;
List<ApplicationInfo> applist;
Listadapter listadapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose option")
            .setItems(R.array.options, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {

                        case 0:
                            ApplicationInfo app3 = applist.get(position);
                            packageName=app3.packageName;
                            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
                            for (Object object : pkgAppsList) {
                                ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
                                File f1 = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
                                try{                          
                                    File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Rahul");
                                    f2.mkdirs();
                                    f2 = new File(f2.getPath()+"/"+packageName + ".apk");
                                    f2.createNewFile();

                                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

                                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

                                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                    int len;
                                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                                    }
                                    in.close();
                                    out.close();
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Copied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
                                }
                                catch(IOException e){
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            });
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)
            .show();

}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return applist;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

        listadapter = new Listadapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "loading apps info,,,");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

}
}
```

[This is the ss of the destination folder in which file gets copied.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBkNF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you was able to get list of installed apps loop as package list but you was not comparing your package name and the name of package which was coming in the loop. So the last app was saved. Please use this hope it will help you. Commented portion is the addition

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    PackageManager packageManager;
    List<ApplicationInfo> applist;
    Listadapter listadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose option").setItems(R.array.options,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {

                        case 0:
                            ApplicationInfo app3 = applist.get(position);

                            // this is the pakage name of tha app you clicked
                            packageName = app3.packageName;
                            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager()
                                    .queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
                            for (Object object : pkgAppsList) {
                                ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
                                // check whther the app clicked and the app in
                                // the loop has same package name
                                if (info.activityInfo.packageName
                                        .equals(packageName)) {
                                    File f1 = new File(
                                            info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
                                    try {
                                        File f2 = new File(Environment
                                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                .toString()
                                                + "/Rahul");
                                        f2.mkdirs();
                                        f2 = new File(f2.getPath() + "/"
                                                + packageName + ".apk");
                                        f2.createNewFile();

                                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

                                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                                f2);

                                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                        int len;
                                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                                        }
                                        in.close();
                                        out.close();
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage()
                                                + " in the specified directory.");
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true).show();

    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
  ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<>();

  for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
      try {
          if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
              applist.add(info);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  return applist;
}

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager
                    .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

            listadapter = new Listadapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            setListAdapter(listadapter);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "loading apps info,,,");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As u can see in image the package name seems to be correct in destination folder but on install contacts.apk gets installed...on easch and everyone

Comment: If u need i can post complete if dats helps

Comment: Once again thanx bro it worked just like i wanted and your way of making the code understand is gud :]

Comment: vishal i need one more favour with this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193080/sharing-specific-apk-from-listview

Comment: Good to see it helped

Comment: If u get some time pls help me wid above question.thanx

Comment: vishal bro...pls have look at my questions i tried researching but i know i have been missing something small and stucked in two places.